# this is a chat box design displaying the sender and receiver messages

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Basically, this code works but it displays both the sender and receiver in the same color
what do i want? i want the sender colour to be different with the receiver message color

```
<?php

require_once 'cn.php';

session_start(); // startsession .line17 (username || usernameto='.$username.')

//messages sent or received by the $_SESSION or $_GET["ident"]..line 26


require_once 'protect.php';

$username=$_SESSION['UserID'];

$fiveMinutesAgo = time() - 1000;

$to=$_SESSION['UserTo'];

$sql = 'SELECT

    username, message_content,message_file, message_time,usernameto

        FROM

    messages

        WHERE

    message_time > ' . $fiveMinutesAgo . '

    and ((username='.$username.'

        and usernameto='.$to.') or (usernameto='.$username.'

        and username='.$to.'))

        ORDER BY
    message_time';

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or

    die(mysql_error($cn));

    //mysql_query ("Update messages set message_file= replace(message_file,' ','');


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $hoursAndMinutes = date('g:ia', $row['message_time']);

    $mycontent=$row['message_content'];

    $myfile=$row['message_file'];

    $playfile="<A href=upload/$myfile> $myfile </A>";
/*************************************************************************************************/


    echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:purple;font-size:15px;"><strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: <em>(' . $hoursAndMinutes . ')</em> ' . $playfile . $mycontent.'</i></p>';
}


?>
```

Comment: How do you know which is the sender and which the receiver?

Comment: @ExplosionPills interesting how people don't participate actively to given comments and answers... like they actually don't even care

Comment: @roXon in their defense they're probably not on the site as consistently as we are

Comment: @ExplosionPills I remember my first questions here, I was actually happy to help someone to help me. and it was good for both sides. For the Answerers to improve answers, and for me cause I really needed an accurate answer as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$username` and your column username contains a userID: Check if `$username` is the same as `$row['username']`. If it is, your message is from the sender.

```
if ($row['username'] == $username)
    $color = 'red';
else
    $color = 'purple';

echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:'.$color.';font-size:15px;"><strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: <em>(' . $hoursAndMinutes . ')</em> ' . $playfile . $mycontent.'</i></p>';
```

Also: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: if you are pleased with my answer, pleace accept it (by clicking the check image).

Answer (score 0):

you need to know when the sendername is the same people who has the session open if the sendername else is the receiver